# jquery mobile two digit decimal

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.45  . While using input as number I want to limit decimal places to two digits.

My input is like below;

```
<input type="number" style="text-align: right" step="0.01" min="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


</style>

<body>

Enter the number : <input type="number" style="text-align: right" step="0.01" min="0" id="mynumber">


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#mynumber").on('keyup',function(){
  var thevalue = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var fixedNum = thevalue.toFixed(2);
  $(this).val(fixedNum);
  
   if (thevalue/fixedNum < 1) 
    {
       alert("please enter only 2 decimal places."); 
    }

});


</script>

</html>
```

hope this will help to you.

Comment: try this with live example

Comment: I did.  But still it is not working. you can't even write numbers